# How to get tree hierarchy for a child node in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I need help in writing in a hierarchical query to get the parent path for a child node. I am trying to use function `sys_connect_by_path` but I am unable to do so because the result of the function having parent title's exceeds max char limit for a `column(4000 chars)`. So I need to hold the path in a custom collection or into a `clob` which I am finding difficult to come up with.

example:

```
contentid        -         parentid
0            -              null
1             -              0
2              -             1
3           -                2
4            -               2
5            -               6
6            -               3
7            -               6
```

Expected result:

```
contentid      -      Expected result set
0           -               null
1              -             0
2            -               1,0
3           -                2,1,0
4           -                2,1,0
5           -                6,3,2,1,0
6           -                3,2,1,0
7           -                6,3,2,1,0
```

Query to get parent path for a child node into a column

```
SELECT CHILD_ID, 
       PATH
 FROM (SELECT sys_connect_by_path(CHILD_TITLE, '|') PATH
            , connect_by_root(PARENT_ID) ROOT_ID, CHILD_ID
        FROM table
     CONNECT BY PRIOR CHILD_ID = PARENT_ID
       ORDER BY CHILD_ID)
WHERE ROOT_ID IS NULL;
```

I need it in a clob/custom collection which can hold more than 4000 characters.

Comment: Just to clarify. Your problem is not with the expected result but rather with 4k limitation?

Comment: yes, my problem is 4k limitation. I am able to get the path using CONNECT BY PRIOR. But the result is expected to exceed 4k limit.

Comment: I have a backup method to create a temp table to the results set into a clob which I am not willing to do as the main table is expected to change frequently and I need to take care about all the child nodes if an intermediate node is removed.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're on 11gR2 or higher you could use [recursive subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#BCEJGIBG) instead of the `connect by` hierarchical syntax.

If your table is called `t` with:

```
  CHILD_ID  PARENT_ID CHILD_T
---------- ---------- -------
         0            root   
         1          0 first  
         2          1 second 
         3          2 third  
         4          2 fourth 
         5          6 fifth  
         6          3 sixth  
         7          6 seventh
```

you can do:

```
with r (child_id, child_title, id_path, title_path) as (
  select child_id, child_title, to_clob(null), to_clob(null)
  from t
  where parent_id is null
  union all
  select t.child_id, t.child_title,
    t.parent_id ||','|| r.id_path, r.child_title ||'|'|| r.title_path
  from r
  join t on t.parent_id = r.child_id
)
select child_id, id_path, title_path
from r
order by child_id;

  CHILD_ID ID_PATH              TITLE_PATH
---------- -------------------- ----------------------------------------
         0
         1 0,                   root|
         2 1,0,                 first|root|
         3 2,1,0,               second|first|root|
         4 2,1,0,               second|first|root|
         5 6,3,2,1,0,           sixth|third|second|first|root|
         6 3,2,1,0,             third|second|first|root|
         7 6,3,2,1,0,           sixth|third|second|first|root|
```

The anchor member turns the paths into CLOBs; the recursive member appends each title to the CLOB, which keeps it as that data type.

You can trim off the trailing comma/bar, or modify the query a bit so they never appear:

```
with r (parent_id, child_id, child_title, id_path, title_path) as (
  select parent_id, child_id, child_title, to_clob(null), to_clob(null)
  from t
  where parent_id is null
  union all
  select t.parent_id, t.child_id, t.child_title,
    t.parent_id || case when r.parent_id is not null then ',' end || r.id_path,
    r.child_title || case when r.parent_id is not null then '|' end || r.title_path
  from r
  join t on t.parent_id = r.child_id
)
select child_id, id_path, title_path
from r
order by child_id;

  CHILD_ID ID_PATH              TITLE_PATH
---------- -------------------- ----------------------------------------
         0
         1 0                    root
         2 1,0                  first|root
         3 2,1,0                second|first|root
         4 2,1,0                second|first|root
         5 6,3,2,1,0            sixth|third|second|first|root
         6 3,2,1,0              third|second|first|root
         7 6,3,2,1,0            sixth|third|second|first|root
```

Your sample values don't demonstrate the need for a CLOB, but adding in more data to the dummy table shows the generated values can exceed 4k:

```
insert into t
select level + 7, level + 6, 'title'
from dual
connect by level <= 2000;

with r (...) -- as above
select max(length(id_path)), max(length(title_path))
from r;

MAX(LENGTH(ID_PATH)) MAX(LENGTH(TITLE_PATH))
-------------------- -----------------------
                8920                   12031
```

Answer (score 0):

`SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` is pretty much an application of `LISTAGG` as demonstrated below: first you generate the rows you need, including `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` and `LEVEL`, and then you aggregate. Doing it a little more explicitly, as I show below, gives you more control over exactly what you want in the aggregate, in what order to use the levels, etc. (*NOTE*: I don't think that is how Oracle does it internally, since `LISTAGG` was added much later than `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`, but logically that's how it works.)

So the problem either way is the 4,000 character limit. Side by side with the `LISTAGG` function, I show a different aggregation, using `XMLAGG` - which does not have the 4,000 character limit. With large input data the `LISTAGG` line will not work, but the `XMLAGG` line will work fine and will produce a CLOB. Good luck!

**Query**:

```
with 
     t ( child_id, parent_id ) as (
       select 0, null from dual union all   
       select 1,    0 from dual union all   
       select 2,    1 from dual union all 
       select 3,    2 from dual union all 
       select 4,    2 from dual union all 
       select 5,    6 from dual union all 
       select 6,    3 from dual union all 
       select 7,    6 from dual
     )
select child_id, 
       listagg(parent_id, ',') within group (order by lvl) as gen_tree_1,
       rtrim(xmlcast(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, parent_id||',') order by lvl) as clob), ',') 
                                                           as gen_tree_2
from   ( select connect_by_root child_id as child_id, parent_id, level as lvl
           from t
           connect by child_id = prior parent_id
       )
group by child_id
order by child_id
;
```

**Output**:

```
  CHILD_ID GEN_TREE_1           GEN_TREE_2
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         0
         1 0                    0
         2 1,0                  1,0
         3 2,1,0                2,1,0
         4 2,1,0                2,1,0
         5 6,3,2,1,0            6,3,2,1,0
         6 3,2,1,0              3,2,1,0
         7 6,3,2,1,0            6,3,2,1,0

8 rows selected.
```